# access the user control property at clinet side

Tags: asp.net, properties, user-controls

I have a User Control - **FilterPanel.ascx** which is used twice on **QuickSearch.aspx**

```
<dx:ASPxRoundPanel ID="filterPanel" ClientInstanceName="filterPanel" runat="server" ShowCollapseButton="True" CssClass="contentPanel" CornerRadius="0">
 <ContentPaddings Padding="0px" />
 <HeaderStyle CssClass="contentPanelHeader" ImageSpacing="0px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" BackColor="#5A81B3" />
 <PanelCollection>
 <dx:PanelContent>
          <dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" ID="txtdxKeyword" Width="139px" Height="18px" Visible="True" NullText="Keyword">
           <ClientSideEvents LostFocus="function(s,e) { FilterCheckbox_CheckChanged(s,'FILTER:TEXTBOX'); }" GotFocus="function(s,e) { CheckMode('FILTER'); }"></ClientSideEvents>
           </dx:ASPxTextBox>
   </dx:PanelContent>
   </PanelCollection>
   </dx:ASPxRoundPanel>
```

**FilterPanel.ascx.cs** got a property **Mode**

```
        public SearchResultsGridUpdateMode Mode { set; get; }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mode == SearchResultsGridUpdateMode.Filter)
            {
                Header = "Filter";
                hfMode.Value = "Filter";
            }
            else if (Mode == SearchResultsGridUpdateMode.Exclusion)
            {
                Header = "Exclusion";
                hfMode.Value = "Exclusion";
            }
            else
                Header = string.Empty;

            filterPanel.HeaderText = Header;
        }
```

**Enum -**

```
 public enum SearchResultsGridUpdateMode
    {
        Filter,
        Exclusion
    }
```

**QuickSearch.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="QuickSearchLeftContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="SearchMasterLeftContentPlaceHolder">
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <uc1:FilterPanel ID="ucFilterPanel" runat="server" Mode="Filter"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <uc1:FilterPanel ID="ucExclusionPanel" runat="server" Mode="Exclusion"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

In **QuickSearch.aspx** I am setting the user control(**FilterPanel.ascx**) value of **Mode** to '**Filter**' or '**Exclusion**'

Now I want to pass the value of **Mode** for ASPxTextBox in any clientside event in **FilterPanel.ascx**

For Example at control **TextBox** on **FilterPanel.ascx**:

GotFocus="function(s,e) { CheckFilterMode(**MODE VALUE**);}

Is that possible to send the UserControl Property value at client side?
Please help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somthing like this.

```
    public SearchResultsGridUpdateMode Mode 
    {
        set
        {
            this.txtdxKeyword.ClientSideEvents.GotFocus = "function(s,e) { CheckMode('" + value.ToString() + "'); }";
            Header = value.ToString;
            hfMode.Value = value.ToString;
        }

        get; 
    }
```

Comment: this.txtdxKeyword.ClientSideEvents.GotFocus = "function(s,e) { CheckMode('" + Mode + "'); }"; is working but how can I write that at client side?

Comment: i want to write something like  <dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" ID="txtdxKeyword" Width="139px" Height="18px" Visible="True" NullText="Keyword">
                                    <ClientSideEvents GotFocus = "function(s,e) { CheckMode('" + Mode + "'); }"></ClientSideEvents>

                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>

Comment: This is because I have many controls where I am mentioning all events on .ascx instead of .ascx.cs page

Comment: You can write server code in you client side *.aspx page like <ClientSideEvents GotFocus = '<%= "function(s,e) { CheckMode('" + this.Mode + "'); }"  %>  but some devexpress controls dosent accept open server tags and ClientSideEventsi think is one of them. But you can try. So if you want to write server tag in client code e.g. ClientID = <%# this.Mode.ToString() %>

Comment: See this link [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q443190)